# Hiding components on page routing in ANGULAR 2

Tags: angular

I got a sidebar component in a main layout component . But it gets added to all the ANGULAR pages .

I need to hide it in a particular page when it routes to it . Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Hi Amar, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [ask] and consider updating your question. In it's current state, this question does not have enough information to help, nor does it demonstrate that you put forth any effort in first trying to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Your question is rather broad and missing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which makes it a bit difficult for people to accurately help you with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data with routing like bool values and show/hide with *ngIf directive. For that there is ActivatedRoute which you can import:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

than add to constructor:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
this.showSidebar = this.route.snapshot.params['showSidebar'];
}
```

Also depending on component from where you navigate to one you don't want to show sidebar, you set routerlink as:

```
[routerLink]="[ '/somelink', showSidebar ]"
```

This all up is raw interpretation so to be precise, please post your code or elaborate more. This method also depends on structure of your components so ...